# Pandas Filter by Regex AND labels combined

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I've got some big csv's. They can easily have over 300k rows and 500 columns. So obviously I like to get rid of some unneeded data in the resulting dataframe to safe resources.
There are some fix labeled columns and also some variable number of columns having similar lables but being numbered.

```
example=pd.DataFrame(columns=["fix","variable 1","variable 2","waste 1","waste 2"])
```

I want to get all these variable columns, which I can get via

```
example.filter(regex="var")
```

but I want to include "fix" as well. As df.loc doesn't allow regex' and df.filter only supports a single argument, is there a smooth way to do this? Or do I have to create a quite complex callable?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your regex to do a full match for "fix":

```
df.filter(regex=r"var|(^fix$)")

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [fix, variable 1, variable 2]
Index: []
```

---

Another option is using `Index.str.contains` in the same fashion:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains(r'var|(?:^fix$)') ]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [fix, variable 1, variable 2]
Index: []
```

I made the group non-capturing, otherwise pandas complains.

Comment: thanks, this works. Still it will get a quite confusing regex but hey ..